# How do I make my buttons fit on screen in Android?

Tags: java, android, view

I have a method that takes a string of text, chops it up and makes buttons out of all the words in the string. I add these to a horizontal Linear Layout like this:

```
for (int x = 0; i < string.length; x++) {
            Button word = new Button(context);
            word.setText(string[x]+"");
            myLinearLayout.addView(word);
        }
```

The problem is that if the string is too long, the buttons will go off screen. How do I make it so that the buttons appear on a line below instead of jumping off screen? I've been looking for a solution all day but couldn't find an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Use shorter text? Use font metrics to get total len of words or a simple algorithm basedon number of letters in all words till current iteration and add a line break if its more than X where X depends on screen width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
   for (int x = 0; i < string.length; x++) {
        Button word = new Button(context);
        word.setText(string[x]+"");
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams left_on = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1);
        word.setLayoutParams(left_on);
        myLinearLayout.addView(word);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! However, it only keeps the buttons inside the view by making them smaller, instead of making a new line. I realize that a horizontal linear layout only can stack views horizontally, but I'm not sure what I should use instead.

Comment: You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html